# Templated comparator as a third argument in find_if

Tags: c++, templates, find, comparator

I have a program that tries to find weak_ptr in vector. It works totally fine. But maybe there is a way to pass templated comparator as a third argument to the find_if? Something similar to TWeakComparator. It will minimize code a lot. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Car
{
};

template<class T>
struct TWeakComparator: private std::unary_function<Car, bool>
{
    explicit TWeakComparator(const T& ptr) : m_comparePtr(ptr) { }
    bool operator()(const T& ptr1) const
    {
        if (ptr1.expired() || m_comparePtr.expired())
            return false;

        return ptr1.lock() == m_comparePtr.lock();
    }
private:
    const T& m_comparePtr;
};

struct WeakComparator: private std::unary_function<Car, bool>
{
    explicit WeakComparator(const std::weak_ptr<Car>& ptr) : m_comparePtr(ptr) { }
    bool operator()(const std::weak_ptr<Car>& ptr1) const
    {
        if (ptr1.expired() || m_comparePtr.expired())
            return false;

        return ptr1.lock() == m_comparePtr.lock();
    }
private:
    const std::weak_ptr<Car>& m_comparePtr;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Car>> cars;

    std::shared_ptr<Car> lambo = std::make_shared<Car>();
    std::weak_ptr<Car> wPtr(lambo);
    cars.emplace_back(lambo);

    const auto pos = std::find_if(cars.begin(), cars.end(), WeakComparator(wPtr));

    if (pos == cars.end())
        std::cout << "Not found!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by templated comparator? I suppose, it would make question clearer if you add pseudo-code to illustrate.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking? You mention possibly using a templated comparator, but then your code doesn't define any class or function templates. Make sure, when you ask a question, that your post contains a clear explanation of your problem.

Comment: Do you want to make a templated functor type that accepts `std::weak_ptr<T>`, not just `std::weak_ptr<Car>`? If so, you should [edit] your question to clarify. Also note that `std::unary_function` is removed from the standard.

Comment: Do you want to make `WeakComparator` a template? If so, what difficulties did you face when you tried to rewrite it to be a template? Can you show us your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `WeakComparator` a class template.

```
template <typename T>
struct WeakComparator : private std::unary_function<T, bool>
{
   explicit WeakComparator(const std::weak_ptr<T>& ptr) : m_comparePtr(ptr) { }
   bool operator()(const std::weak_ptr<T>& ptr1) const
   {
      if (ptr1.expired() || m_comparePtr.expired())
         return false;

      return ptr1.lock() == m_comparePtr.lock();
   }
   private:
   const std::weak_ptr<T>& m_comparePtr;
};
```

and then use

```
const auto pos = std::find_if(cars.begin(), cars.end(), WeakComparator<T>(wPtr));
```

If you are able to use C++17, you can omit the `<T>` part and use

```
const auto pos = std::find_if(cars.begin(), cars.end(), WeakComparator(wPtr));
```

Otherwise, you can use a helper function to reduce redundancy:

```
template <typename T>
WeakComparator<T> makeWeakComparator(const std::weak_ptr<T>& ptr)
{
   return WeakComparator<T>(ptr);
}
```

and use

```
const auto pos = std::find_if(cars.begin(), cars.end(), makeWeakComparator(wPtr));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I think with C++17 CTAD we don't even need `makeWeakComparator`, as `WeakComparator(wPtr)` should work just fine.